# How do i create a list of indices divisible by a number in R?

Tags: r

Given a vector, x =  c(..........), how would I find the indices that are divisible by a number, for example 5, and use that to sum up the values of those indices using the seq() function? I tried using seq() but it would only grab the values that are divisible by 5, not the actual indices.

Comment: Please post some sample input and the output you want.

Comment: And also what exactly you tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `which` with `%%` operator:

```
v <- c(1:50)
which(v%%5==0)
```

```
[1]  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
```

Comment: This is what I was doing before and it was wrong. I'm not looking for the values that are divisible by 5, rather I'm looking for the indices

Comment: @Grim, note that these are not the values but the indices. change v to be `v <- seq_along(your_vector)`

Answer (score 1):

```r
vec <- 1:20

(seq_along(vec)-1) %% 5 == 0
#  [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
sum(vec[(seq_along(vec)-1) %% 5 == 0])
# [1] 34

seq(1, length(vec), by = 5)
# [1]  1  6 11 16
sum(vec[seq(1, length(vec), by = 5)])
# [1] 34
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for my question